# Getting around devise authentication requirement

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to not require authentication for my reports view action.  However when I try to use the devise method skip_before_action or skip_before_filter, it will still revert me back to the login page.

Here is my application controller.

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :require_user

  layout :check_layout

  protected

  def check_layout
    devise_controller? ? 'legacy' : nil
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email) }
  end

  private

  def require_user
    authenticate_user!
  end
end
```

Here is my reports controller

```
    class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :require_user, only: [:view]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:transition]
  before_action :check_params, only: [:transition]
  before_action :set_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :draft, :copy_edit, :review_and_approve, :revise, :approve, :archive, :mail_merge, :draft_from_queue]

end
```

How do I do I go about not requiring authentication for the report view action?

Comment: Can you post the logs for this action execution?

Comment: Started GET "/reports" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-07-31 23:48:55 +0000
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by ReportsController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 29ms


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-07-31 23:48:55 +0000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/legacy (63.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_datatables.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered application/_analytics.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 562ms (Views: 544.1ms |

Answer (score 1):

Your filters look ok, but the problem is that you are not hitting the view action. You are hitting the index action:

```
Started GET "/reports" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-07-31 23:48:55 +0000
...
Processing by ReportsController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 29ms
```